# Adding additional field in Response Object

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, jackson-databind

I am getting below response when I am calling an API.

```
 Response postRequestResponse = ConnectionUtil.getwebTarget()
                        .property(ClientProperties.SUPPRESS_HTTP_COMPLIANCE_VALIDATION, true)
                        .path("bots")
                        .path(ReadSkillID.readSkillId())
                        .path("dynamicEntities").path(dynamicEntityID)
                        .path("pushRequests").path(pushRequestID).path(operation)
                        .request()
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + ConnectionUtil.getToken())
                        .get();
```

Below output I am getting.

```
 {
        "createdOn": "2020-08-17T12:19:13.541Z",
        "updatedOn": "2020-08-17T12:19:23.421Z",
        "id": "C84B058A-C8F9-41F5-A353-EC2CFE7A1BD9",
        "status": "TRAINING",
        "statusMessage": "Request Pushed into training, on user request"
    }
```

I have to return this  output to client with an additional field in the response. How can modify the above response and make it

```
{
         "EntityName": "NewEntity",   //New field
        "createdOn": "2020-08-17T12:19:13.541Z",
        "updatedOn": "2020-08-17T12:19:23.421Z",
        "id": "C84B058A-C8F9-41F5-A353-EC2CFE7A1BD9",
        "status": "TRAINING",
        "statusMessage": "Request Pushed into training, on user request"
   }
```

I am adding this additional field here
"EntityName": "NewEntity"

How can I do that. many things I tried but got exception.

Comment: Which HTTP Client are you using? Post the complete class.

Comment: Can you give us more details, the class that you get that snippet from, and what is `ReadSkillID.readSkillId()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. get JSON from `postRequestResponse` (i have no idea what framework you are using, so you have to figer it out on your own, but the Response datatype will probably have a getResponseBody or similar method returing the JSON)
2. add EntityName
3. serialize it again to json.

```
class YourBean {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public void yourMethod() {
        // 1
        final InputStream jsonFromResponse = ...

        // 2
        Map dataFromResponse = objectMapper.readValue(jsonFromResponse, Map.class);
        dataFromResponse.put("EntityName", "NewEntity");

        // 3
        final String enrichedJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dataFromResponse);
    }
}
```

`enrichedJson` contains EntityName and whatever comes from the API.